# how to use If statement on Plotly visualisation "mode"

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I want to draw a plolty 'marker+lines' if the value of df['A_info'] is 'nan' else draw 'makers'. What could be the problem and how can i achieve the output.

I am unfortunately receiving error On the following line: mode = 'markers+lines' if df['A_info'].isnull() else 'markers',

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
d={'A':[3,3,2,1,5],
   'B':[4,4,1,4,7],
   'A_info':['nothing', np.nan, np.nan, 'bad', 'good'],
   'B_info':[np.nan, np.nan, 'bad', 'better', 'best']}

df=pd.DataFrame(d, index=[10,11,12,13,14])

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['A'],
    mode = 'markers+lines',
    hovertext=df['A_info'],
    hoverinfo="text",
    marker=dict(
        color="blue"
    ),
    showlegend=False
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['B'],
    mode = 'markers+lines' if df['A_info'].isnull() else 'markers', 
    hovertext=df['B_info'],
    hoverinfo="text",
    marker=dict(
        color="green"
    ),
    showlegend=False
))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're missing colons in your if else structure `'markers+lines' if df['A_info'].isnull() else 'markers'`. But trying to correct this will not help. `mode` in `fig.add_trace` accepts a single string and not an array or list of strings.

So how can you obtain:

> I want to draw a plolty 'marker+lines' if the value of df['A_info'] is
> 'nan' else draw 'makers'

Plotly will do this for you right out of the box. The code snippet below will produce the following figure where values have markers and `np.nan` shows nothing:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1,2,3,np.nan, np.nan,4]})

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=df.index, y=df.value, mode = 'markers')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out but this doesn't solve my dilemma. What i want to achieve is that, I want the "mode" to accept a drawing argument based on conditional if statement.

Comment: @EmmanuelAdonyo I believe I have in fact answered that question. It seems that this question is about an approach that will help you obtain some goal that you have not yet described;`...to accept a drawing argument`. So you should really ask about how to achieve your goal, and not ask why your attempt to reach that goal fails. And the approach you have chosen will fail either way, since mode *only* accepts as string and not a list of strings with, for example, `['markers', 'markers+lines'...]`